# MVC2 Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a few routing issues with my ASP.NET MVC2 website and was wondering if there is a way I can get the runtime to simple list of all of the routes it thinks it understands.

Some thing like the fubu diagnostics would be handy ...
[alt text http://guides.fubumvc.com/images/guides1diags.png](http://guides.fubumvc.com/images/guides1diags.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this excellent [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) from Phil Haacked. It is an indispensable tool for ASP.NET MVC development.